Installation of rgdal package from source fails
When I try to build the rdgal package from source, it fails.
It is clear that I need a package that looks like libdeflate or a lot of else, but my search only found how to get it into Linux, but not Windows 10.
How can this be done?
I hope it will work well.
> install.packages("rgdal_1.6-7.tar.gz",type="source",repos = NULL)
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Lenovo/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.4’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
* installing *source* package 'rgdal' ...
** package 'rgdal' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation

   **********************************************
   WARNING: this package has a configure script
         It probably needs manual configuration
   **********************************************


** libs
using C compiler: 'gcc.exe (GCC) 13.2.0'
using C++ compiler: 'G__~1.EXE (GCC) 13.2.0'
using C++17
~I Omit the code~
C:\rtools44\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: C:/rtools44/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/lib/libgdal.a(LERC_band.cpp.obj):LERC_band.cpp:(.text+0x343): undefined reference to `lerc_getBlobInfo'
C:\rtools44\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: C:/rtools44/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/lib/libgdal.a(LERC_band.cpp.obj):LERC_band.cpp:(.text+0x714): undefined reference to `lerc_decode'
C:\rtools44\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: C:/rtools44/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/lib/libgdal.a(LERC_band.cpp.obj):LERC_band.cpp:(.text+0x3313): undefined reference to `lerc_encodeForVersion'
C:\rtools44\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: C:/rtools44/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/lib/libfreetype.a(sfnt.o): in function `woff2_decompress':
/root/mxe/tmp-freetype-x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/freetype-2.13.2/src/sfnt/sfwoff2.c:326:(.text+0xf35b): undefined reference to `BrotliDecoderDecompress'
C:\rtools44\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: C:/rtools44/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/lib/libcurl.a(libcurl_la-psl.o):psl.c:(.text+0x31): undefined reference to `psl_free'
C:\rtools44\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: C:/rtools44/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/lib/libcurl.a(libcurl_la-psl.o):psl.c:(.text+0xcd): undefined reference to `psl_latest'
C:\rtools44\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: C:/rtools44/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/lib/libcurl.a(libcurl_la-psl.o):psl.c:(.text+0x107): undefined reference to `psl_free'
C:\rtools44\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: C:/rtools44/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/lib/libcurl.a(libcurl_la-psl.o):psl.c:(.text+0x177): undefined reference to `psl_builtin'
C:\rtools44\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: C:/rtools44/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/lib/libcurl.a(libcurl_la-version.o):version.c:(.text+0x122): undefined reference to `BrotliDecoderVersion'
C:\rtools44\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: C:/rtools44/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/lib/libcurl.a(libcurl_la-version.o):version.c:(.text+0x209): undefined reference to `psl_check_version_number'
C:\rtools44\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: C:/rtools44/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/lib/libcurl.a(libcurl_la-version.o):version.c:(.text+0x357): undefined reference to `BrotliDecoderVersion'
C:\rtools44\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: C:/rtools44/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/lib/libcurl.a(libcurl_la-version.o):version.c:(.text+0x362): undefined reference to `BrotliDecoderVersion'
C:\rtools44\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: C:/rtools44/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/lib/libcurl.a(libcurl_la-content_encoding.o):content_encodi:(.text+0x222): undefined reference to `BrotliDecoderDestroyInstance'
C:\rtools44\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: C:/rtools44/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/lib/libcurl.a(libcurl_la-content_encoding.o):content_encodi:(.text+0x2dc): undefined reference to `BrotliDecoderDecompressStream'
C:\rtools44\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: C:/rtools44/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/lib/libcurl.a(libcurl_la-content_encoding.o):content_encodi:(.text+0x339): undefined reference to `BrotliDecoderDestroyInstance'
C:\rtools44\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: C:/rtools44/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/lib/libcurl.a(libcurl_la-content_encoding.o):content_encodi:(.text+0x385): undefined reference to `BrotliDecoderGetErrorCode'
C:\rtools44\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: C:/rtools44/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/lib/libcurl.a(libcurl_la-content_encoding.o):content_encodi:(.text+0x410): undefined reference to `BrotliDecoderCreateInstance'
C:\rtools44\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: C:/rtools44/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/lib/libcurl.a(libcurl_la-cookie.o):cookie.c:(.text+0x1166): undefined reference to `psl_is_cookie_domain_acceptable'
C:\rtools44\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: C:/rtools44/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/lib/libtiff.a(tif_lerc.o): in function `LERCCleanup':
/root/mxe/tmp-tiff-x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/tiff-4.6.0/libtiff/tif_lerc.c:966:(.text+0xf1): undefined reference to `libdeflate_free_decompressor'
C:\rtools44\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: /root/mxe/tmp-tiff-x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/tiff-4.6.0/libtiff/tif_lerc.c:968:(.text+0xff): undefined reference to `libdeflate_free_compressor'
C:\rtools44\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: C:/rtools44/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/lib/libtiff.a(tif_lerc.o): in function `LERCPostEncode':
/root/mxe/tmp-tiff-x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/tiff-4.6.0/libtiff/tif_lerc.c:801:(.text+0x56f): undefined reference to `lerc_encodeForVersion'
C:\rtools44\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: /root/mxe/tmp-tiff-x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/tiff-4.6.0/libtiff/tif_lerc.c:837:(.text+0x7ad): undefined reference to `libdeflate_zlib_compress_bound'
C:\rtools44\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: /root/mxe/tmp-tiff-x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/tiff-4.6.0/libtiff/tif_lerc.c:845:(.text+0x7da): undefined reference to `libdeflate_zlib_compress'
C:\rtools44\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: /root/mxe/tmp-tiff-x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/tiff-4.6.0/libtiff/tif_lerc.c:824:(.text+0x83e): undefined reference to `libdeflate_alloc_compressor'
C:\rtools44\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: C:/rtools44/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/lib/libtiff.a(tif_lerc.o): in function `LERCPreDecode':
/root/mxe/tmp-tiff-x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/tiff-4.6.0/libtiff/tif_lerc.c:331:(.text+0xeff): undefined reference to `libdeflate_zlib_decompress'
C:\rtools44\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: /root/mxe/tmp-tiff-x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/tiff-4.6.0/libtiff/tif_lerc.c:403:(.text+0xf3d): undefined reference to `lerc_getBlobInfo'
C:\rtools44\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: /root/mxe/tmp-tiff-x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/tiff-4.6.0/libtiff/tif_lerc.c:476:(.text+0x1037): undefined reference to `lerc_decode'
C:\rtools44\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: /root/mxe/tmp-tiff-x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/tiff-4.6.0/libtiff/tif_lerc.c:323:(.text+0x1269): undefined reference to `libdeflate_alloc_decompressor'
C:\rtools44\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: /root/mxe/tmp-tiff-x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/tiff-4.6.0/libtiff/tif_lerc.c:476:(.text+0x1382): undefined reference to `lerc_decode'
C:\rtools44\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: C:/rtools44/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/lib/libtiff.a(tif_lerc.o): in function `LERCVSetField':
/root/mxe/tmp-tiff-x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/tiff-4.6.0/libtiff/tif_lerc.c:1103:(.text+0x16a4): undefined reference to `libdeflate_free_compressor'
C:\rtools44\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: C:/rtools44/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/lib/libtiff.a(tif_zip.o): in function `ZIPCleanup':
/root/mxe/tmp-tiff-x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/tiff-4.6.0/libtiff/tif_zip.c:551:(.text+0xbd): undefined reference to `libdeflate_free_decompressor'
C:\rtools44\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: /root/mxe/tmp-tiff-x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/tiff-4.6.0/libtiff/tif_zip.c:553:(.text+0xce): undefined reference to `libdeflate_free_compressor'
C:\rtools44\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: C:/rtools44/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/lib/libtiff.a(tif_zip.o): in function `ZIPEncode':
/root/mxe/tmp-tiff-x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/tiff-4.6.0/libtiff/tif_zip.c:423:(.text+0x2d7): undefined reference to `libdeflate_zlib_compress_bound'
C:\rtools44\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: /root/mxe/tmp-tiff-x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/tiff-4.6.0/libtiff/tif_zip.c:430:(.text+0x312): undefined reference to `libdeflate_zlib_compress'
C:\rtools44\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: /root/mxe/tmp-tiff-x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/tiff-4.6.0/libtiff/tif_zip.c:405:(.text+0x3a3): undefined reference to `libdeflate_alloc_compressor'
C:\rtools44\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: C:/rtools44/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/lib/libtiff.a(tif_zip.o): in function `ZIPDecode':
/root/mxe/tmp-tiff-x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/tiff-4.6.0/libtiff/tif_zip.c:215:(.text+0x832): undefined reference to `libdeflate_zlib_decompress'
C:\rtools44\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: /root/mxe/tmp-tiff-x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/tiff-4.6.0/libtiff/tif_zip.c:206:(.text+0x948): undefined reference to `libdeflate_alloc_decompressor'
C:\rtools44\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: C:/rtools44/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/lib/libtiff.a(tif_zip.o): in function `ZIPVSetField':
/root/mxe/tmp-tiff-x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/tiff-4.6.0/libtiff/tif_zip.c:597:(.text+0xb9b): undefined reference to `libdeflate_free_compressor'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
no DLL was created
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'rgdal'
* removing 'C:/Users/Lenovo/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.4/rgdal'
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘rgdal_1.6-7.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status

The session information is as below.
I uses RTools4.4 to build the source file.
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.4.0 (2024-04-24 ucrt)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64
Running under: Windows 11 x64 (build 22000)

Matrix products: default


locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_Indonesia.utf8  LC_CTYPE=English_Indonesia.utf8   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_Indonesia.utf8 LC_NUMERIC=C                      
[5] LC_TIME=English_Indonesia.utf8   

time zone: Asia/Jakarta
tzcode source: internal

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] miniUI_0.1.1.1    compiler_4.4.0    promises_1.3.0    Rcpp_1.0.12       stringr_1.5.1    
 [6] later_1.3.2       fastmap_1.2.0     mime_0.12         R6_2.5.1          htmlwidgets_1.6.4
[11] tibble_3.2.1      profvis_0.3.8     shiny_1.8.1.1     pillar_1.9.0      rlang_1.1.3      
[16] utf8_1.2.4        cachem_1.1.0      stringi_1.8.4     httpuv_1.6.15     fs_1.6.4         
[21] pkgload_1.3.4     memoise_2.0.1     cli_3.6.2         magrittr_2.0.3    digest_0.6.35    
[26] rstudioapi_0.16.0 xtable_1.8-4      remotes_2.5.0     devtools_2.4.5    lifecycle_1.0.4  
[31] vctrs_0.6.5       glue_1.7.0        urlchecker_1.0.1  sessioninfo_1.2.2 pkgbuild_1.4.4   
[36] fansi_1.0.6       purrr_1.0.2       pkgconfig_2.0.3   tools_4.4.0       usethis_2.2.3    
[41] ellipsis_0.3.2    htmltools_0.5.8.1

